# I have an Unexpected String error in my Javascript Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I have a big problem with a script in my Prestashop.

I have an error : "Uncaught SyntaxError : Unexpected string".

This is the script :

```
{if $ajaxsearch}
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    $('document').ready( function() {
        $("#search_query_{$blocksearch_type}")
            .autocomplete(
                '{if $search_ssl == 1}{$link->getPageLink('search', true)}{else}{$link->getPageLink('search')}{/if}', {
                    minChars: 3,
                    max: 10,
                    width: 500,
                    selectFirst: false,
                    scroll: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    formatItem: function(data, i, max, value, term) {
                        return value;
                    },
                    parse: function(data) {
                        var mytab = new Array();
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                            mytab[mytab.length] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].cname + " > " + data[i].pname };
                        }
                        return mytab;
                    },
                    extraParams: {
                        ajaxSearch: 1,
                        id_lang: {$cookie->id_lang}
                    }
                }
            )
            .result(function(event, data, formatted) {
                $('#search_query_{$blocksearch_type}').val(data.pname);
                document.location.href = data.product_link;
            })
    });
// ]]>
</script>
```

{/if}

The code is in a TPL view in a prestashop Module.

This is a screenshot of the error in the console of Google Chrome :

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I need your help please...

Answer (score 2):

`'{if $search_ssl == 1}{$link->getPageLink('search', t…` is the syntax error that is being complained about.

You can't have unescaped `'` characters inside a string delimited with `'` characters.

It looks like you are trying to generate JavaScript from PHP but forgot the `<?php` and `?>`.

Comment: Thank you... See my answer below please

Answer (score 0):

You cat't  put  **'** between **'  '**

use "\" before it.

```
 '{if $search_ssl == 1}{$link->getPageLink(\'search\', true)}{else}{$link->getPageLink(\'search\')}{/if}', {
```

Comment: Thank you... See my answer below